# jQuery append to vanilla javascript issue when injecting a facebook pixel in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, facebook-pixel

I have written a script which I have in the head section on my landing pages. What it does is that it loads a facebook pixel which I have stored in another part of my application which I access by calling an endpoint. This because I need to dynamically change the script without interfering with the code on the landing page itself. This code is written in Jquery but now I need jQuery gone from my application so I've tried to rewrite it using only vanilla javascript.

The problem is that it works just fine with the jQuery code, but when I've tried to replace it with vanilla Javascript it does not seem to inject the code in the correct way. The output in the DOM looks exactly the same but it does not fire the pixel somehow.

So my question is. Why is this?

Here is the working example of my jQuery script

```
<script>
  $.get('https://api.mydomain.com/script', function (data) {
    $('head').append(data);
  });
</script>
```

Here is my vanilla Javascript version

```
<script>
  var theUrl = 'https://api.mydomain.com/script';
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", theUrl);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", xhr.response);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: What's the value of `xhr.response`?

Comment: @user7290573 the value of xhr.response is the exact same as the content that exists in a facebook pixel.

Comment: Here is an example: <script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXX'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>

Comment: So it inserts that at the end of the head tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with `insertAdjacentHTML` - just a guess, but maybe it only works for HTML (divs, images, etc.) rather than scripts. Hopefully this workaround is an acceptable solution:

```js
(function() {
    const
        exampleScript = getScriptContent(`
            <script>
                alert("example script loaded");
            <\/script>
        `),
        s = document.createElement("script"),
        t = document.createTextNode(exampleScript);

    s.appendChild(t);

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);

    function getScriptContent(htmlStr) {
        const tempDiv = document.createElement("div");

        tempDiv.innerHTML = htmlStr;

        return tempDiv.innerText;
    }
})();
```